# Is it significantly better to use ISO-8859-1 rather than UTF-8 wherever possible?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, storage

For globalization of scripts, it is very common to use `UTF-8` as the default charset; for example in HTML or default charset of mysql. This is also the case for latin website in which characters are in the class of `ISO-8859-1`. Isn't it advantageous to use `ISO-8859-1` when `UTF-8` characters are not needed. From advantageous, I mean critically beneficial.

My point is that only 0 - 127 characters of `UTF-8` are 1 byte, and from 128 - 255 are 2-byte; where `ISO-8859-1` is 1 byte system. Doesn't it play a critical role in database storage?

Comment: "Better" is so unspecific as to mean very little. What, exactly, are the qualities you're comparing? What are you trying to improve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of these 127 `UTF-8` 1-byte characters are the most used when you work with `ISO-8859-1`. Let's have a look **[here](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/)**. If you use `UTF-8` you will need 1 extra byte *only* when you use one of the 127-255 characters (**[not](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/iso160-191.gif) so [commons](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/iso192-223.gif) I [bet](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/iso224-255.gif)**).

My opinion? Use `UTF-8` if you can and if you haven't problem handling it. The time you save the day you will need some extra characters (or the day you have to translate your content) really worth a few extra bytes here and there in the DB...

Answer (score 5):

If everything you need now and forever is ISO-8859-1, you'll save space by using it, though likely not much if most of the characters used are < 128. If you ever need to use anything outside of ISO-8859-1, you'll be in a world of hurt. From an overall perspective, the cost in storage for UTF-8 is way lower than the cost of implementing multiple encodings.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: It doesn't matter.

Long(er) answer: Think of it that way. You have a `message` table that contains the messages of a forum. You have a lot of messages (let's say, 1 million). Assume every message takes 10 extra bytes due to UTF-8. That's 10 millions extra character, which is not even 10MB (not counting index).

For such a "popular" forum, you will not use more than 15MB of storage at most. That's nothing. You should definitely not worry about the extra bytes lost, and UTF-8 will provide benefits that are much more important than 10 MB.

Answer (score 1):

## Does size matter?

As you know, the characters in the range U+0080 to U+009F take up twice as much space in UTF-8 as they do in ISO-8859-1.  But, how often do these characters get used?

In a typical Spanish text I got from the front page of Wikipedia:

> Artículo bueno
>
> La séptima temporada de la serie de televisión de dibujos animados Los
>   Simpson fue emitida originalmente por la cadena Fox entre el 17 de
>   septiembre de 1995 y el 19 de mayo de 1996. Los productores ejecutivos
>   de la séptima temporada fueron Bill Oakley y Josh Weinstein, quienes
>   producirían 21 episodios de la temporada. David Mirkin fue el show
>   runner de los cuatro restantes, incluyendo dos vestigios que habían
>   sido producidos para la temporada anterior. La séptima temporada
>   estuvo nominada para dos Premios Primetime Emmy, incluyendo la
>   categoría "Mejor programa animado (de duración menor a una hora)" y
>   obtuvo un Premio Annie por "Mejor programa animado de televisión". La
>   versión en DVD fue lanzada a la venta en la Región 1 el 13 de
>   diciembre de 2005, en la Región 2 el 30 de enero de 2006 y en la
>   Región 4 el 29 de marzo del mismo año. La caja recopilatoria fue
>   puesta a la venta en dos formatos diferentes: una caja con la forma de
>   la cabeza de Marge y otra rectangular clásica, en la cual el dibujo
>   muestra el estreno de una película.

There are 17 non-ASCII characters in a sea of 1044 ASCII characters.  That means an expansion of only 1.6% expansion when encoding in UTF-8.  Hardly worth worrying about, especially when the all-ASCII HTML markup is taken into account.

(However, the difference may be significant for a more heavily-accented language like [Sango](http://sg.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A4_nz%C3%B6n%C3%AE).)

## How would your idea work, anyway?

Are you going to encode all your data in windows-1252?  That doesn't give you globalization; the globe does not stop at the Oder River.  True ISO-8859-1 (lacking €) is even worse; the globe does not stop at the English Channel.

Tag text with its encoding?  That works for XML, HTML, and SMTP.  But you asked:

> Doesn't it play a critical role in database storage?

How do you intend to store mixed Latin-1 and UTF-8 strings in a database?

Have two columns `EncodedText BLOB, IsUtf8 BOOLEAN`?  How are you gonna query that?  Surely you won't just look at `EncodedText` and ignore `IsUtf8`; that approach leads to mojibake.

You *could* write a view with a column `CASE WHEN IsUtf8 THEN EncodedText ELSE Latin1ToUtf8(EncodedText) END`, and a proper `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, but that's likely to cost you more bytes than it saves.